# How to get the remaining string after removing a substring

Tags: c#, .net, regex, string

Suppose, I have the following string:

```
string temp = "some string contains text which contains demo";
string result = RemainingString(temp, 12, 8); // string, startIndex, length
```

The result string I need should look as follows:

```
some string text which contains demo
```

Note, that the word *contains* is removed from first place only.

**Update:** I personally want to achieve this using regular expression explicitly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution using regular expressions:

```
public string RemainingString(string str, int start, int length)
{
    return Regex.Replace(str, "^(.{" + start+ "})(?:.{" + length + "})(.*)$", "$1$2");
}
```

Comment: @AbhishekGupta A very wise man once said: "I had a problem. I solved it with a Regex. Now I have two problems." - Only use regexes where they're appropriate. I'd suggest that the string.Remove method is more suited to your purpose. EPLKleijntjens It's always good to consider different solutions though, +1 for that! (Update - have just seen OPs comment on using regex, good answer!)

Comment: I was actually creating a utility in WPF to create repository of reg ex for such basic tasks

Answer (score 7):

Try the [String.Remove](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.remove.aspx) method, it does exactly what you ask.

Answer (score 5):

[String.Remove(Int32, Int32)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d8d7z2kk%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) will do the job:

```
string temp = "some string contains text which contains demo";
string result = temp.Remove(12,8);
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `string.Remove`:

```
public string RemainingString(string orig, int startIndex, int length)
{
    return orig.Remove(startIndex, length);
}
```

Alternatively - concatenate two substrings - up to the index, and after the index+length (.NET 1.0/1.1):

```
public string RemainingString(string orig, int startIndex, int length)
{
    return orig.Substring(0, startIndex) + 
           orig.Substring(startIndex + length);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
   $line_string = 'this is all the sting from which i would want to treat';

    $key_string ='from which';

    //use strpos

    $position2 = strpos($line_string,$key);

   if($position2){

      $found = substr($line_string,$position2,strlen($key_string));

      //echo $found;

    }

    //the substr now begins at character position $position2

    //and ends at position2 + strlen($key_string);

     //so
     $remainderpos = position2 + strlen($key_string);


     $str_remaining = substr($line_string,$remainderpos);

     echo $str_remaining;
```

as simple as it can get. code from the scratch.

Comment: This looks like a PHP code, you know the OP codes in C# right?